# How to insert/append new node entries to an element list in WSO2 BPEL?

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process

Using wso2bps-3.5.1

I have searched but not found any information on how to dynamicaly populate a list of elements in WSO2 BPS BPEL.

My use case is to loop through a list given from an Invoke activity to produce another list of elements. I'm using a Foreach activity to loop where I create a local scoped variable inside the loop to build the new list entry. But, I have no idea how to insert this node into the new list. Are there any built in functions?

Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this question my self:

```
    xmlns:test="http://ode/bpel/unit-test.wsdl"
    queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath2.0"
    expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath2.0"
...
<bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign">
        <bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from>
                <![CDATA[ode:insert-after($closeAccountResponse.closeAccountResponsePart/xclac:accountConnections, $closeAccountResponse.closeAccountResponsePart/xclac:accountConnections/xcom:accountConnection, $record)]]>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="closeAccountResponsePart" variable="closeAccountResponse">
                <bpel:query><![CDATA[xclac:accountConnections]]></bpel:query>
            </bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
    </bpel:assign>
```

Comment: I did this but I have the error "Namespace not found for prefix "ode"". How can I fix this???